# Clustering Metrics for large data

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset containing 150k rows and 10 columns. After clustering, I would like to get clustering metrics. Below are lists of metrics that I would like to use>

```
 "C_index", "Calinski_Harabasz", "Davies_Bouldin", "S_Dbw", "Silhouette"
```

I have a problem. I've tried getting values using `clusterCrit` (from R) and `sklearn` (from python), but when I tried to get each value by using clusterCrit, it took a huge amount of time, so I couldn't get it.

I think this is because of the large data (my RAM is 8GB). Is there any way for me to get these values?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a subsample of your data.

There is little use in evaluating (nor clustering, usually) the entire data set. It's highly redundant. Trying to scale this to the entire data set is a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I'm new to this, I want to ask about your answer specifically. I have 2 questions.


1. When I do clustering with lot of methods (Spectral, Agglomerative, DBSCAN, OPTICS, Kmeans, ...), if I fit sample data and predict other rest data, can I consider that whole result as validated result?


2. Also, when I divide the clustering result into sample result and get clustering metrics, can I say it is meaningful to all data??

Comment: How can you say it is meaningful even if you had used all data? All data is also just a sample. The purpose of clustering is not to maximize some index.